# JOIN datasets via GROUP ALL

Tags: apache-pig

This question might sounds very weird, but it is always on my mind. Let's assume that I have a one-column set of data. How could I place a static string next to a second column for every line available? So if the first line of the single-column dataset says "hello", the two-column equivalent should say "hello", "world".

In case you are wondering why I what to do that, it is because, later in my script I need to join the single column dataset with another one, where the former has no point of reference. This is what I have done so far:

```
fnl2 = FOREACH fnl1 GENERATE
var1,
(var1 == var1 ? 'World' : 'World') AS var2;
```

In case this can be done by group all or something similar, please feel to provide your hints.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but the bincond is unnecessary.  You can just do

```
fnl2 = FOREACH fnl1 GENERATE var1, 'World' AS var2;
```

But even this is not necessary if you are doing this so you can perform a `JOIN` later.  `JOIN` takes expressions as well as fields, so you can just do

```
joined = JOIN fnl1 BY 1, other BY 1;
```

But even THIS is unnecessary, because you are just performing a cross-product, and Pig is one step ahead of you:

```
crossed = CROSS fnl1, other;
```

The last statement is what I think you are looking for, but hopefully the others illustrate some helpful points for you.